# About some balance terminology

Tags: balances

## Background

when reading the code about `pallet balance` and some low-level code.I notice some `terminology` about balance.

## terminology

- Burn
- Slash
- Reserve
- Lock
- Withdraw
- deposit

What is the meaning and specific difference of the above terminology, I have some doubts about this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- *Burn*: To remove some balance or asset from issuance.
- *Slash*: The reduce an account's balance as punishment.
- *Reserve*: To set aside some account's balance so it cannot be used in any other way but is still associated with the owner.
- *Lock*: To set a lower-limit on the account balance so a transfer or other elective balance-reducing operation cannot reduce it below this amount. Unlike with reserving, multiple locks on the same account "overlap".
- *Withdraw*: To reduce the balance of an account. There is an expectation that this is a counterpart to some other operation(s) which will leave a deficit of tokens and thus that by doing both/all operations, the *total issuance* across the system will be correctly accounted.
- *Deposit*: To increase the balance of an account. There is an expectation that this is a counterpart to some previous operation(s) which left a surplus of tokens and thus that by doing both/all operations, the *total issuance* across the system will be correctly accounted.

Comment: thank you very much, i got it !

Comment: Thanks for your response. There is also `Endowed`. What does it mean?