# Is it possible to allow vesting balances to participant in staking and/or democracy

Tags: staking, democracy, vesting

Is there any prior work on allowing vesting accounts to participate in staking/democracy pallets?

To be clear, I would like to use a locked balance from the vesting pallet to vote/stake.

Answer (score 0):

Locks can [overlap](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/2382/2005), so you [can](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/3682/2005) definitely use locked funds from `vesting` to  `stake` or `vote`.